# Android app - show "Change Keyboard" settings dialog

Tags: java, android, keyboard, dialog, settings

I am developing an android app in Java that needs to be set up as a keyboard.

I want to have a button that when the user presses my app shows the following dialog box:

[image]

This is a quick settings dialog box to allow the user to choose the input method (keyboard) it wants to use from now on. It is a default Android setting that is accessible to any user.

Normally this setting shows up when you press the following shortcut next to the android navigation bar when a keyboard is opened:

[image]

But in the context I am working on, this option is not visible to the user. So I want my app to be able to show this setting to the user when it presses a button.

I know an app that does this exact thing, so I know that it is possible. However, I don't know how to code a button that displays a system dialog box like this one.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I found the answer using an InputMethodManager object and the showInputMethodPicker() method in Java:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```